# HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) using Nginx RTMP server hosted on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, http-live-streaming, rtmp

**Goal**:

Mobile ➡️ RTMP Stream to Server ➡️ RTMP to HLS Transcoding ➡️ Playback in HLS player/VLC using HTTP link.

I have hosted the Nginx RTMP server on the Google Kubernetes Engine.
I can playback the live stream in VLC using rtmp://:1935/app/test
But unable to playback using HLS.

i.e `http://<IP>:8080/live/test.m3u8`.

**VLC log:**

```
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

main: playlist is empty

access error: HTTP connection failure

http error: cannot connect to <IP>:8080
```

**HLS Player**

Also, when I play it using HLS player https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/ it shows the following error in console:

```
main.js:565 Error event: {type: "networkError", details: "manifestLoadTimeOut", fatal: true, url: "http://<IP>:8080/live/test.m3u8", loader: XhrLoader, …}

Fatal error :manifestLoadTimeOut
```

**Hosting the server on a local machine:**

When I hosted the server on my local machine I can playback the stream using HLS in VLC and HLS player.

So is there any issue with HTTP Live Streaming(HLS) on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Comment: Can you ping the port directly with telnet? maybe is a mapping or firewall issue

Comment: how are you exposing your service?